# SQL Full Text Breaking SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We have new entries not updating for our fulltextsearch field. We found this article https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5996/tsql-script-to-correct-sql-server-full-text-indexes-not-updating/ basically it says to turn FTS to manual then automatic and it should resolve FTS field not updating. We did it but it ended up crashing our sql server.

We aren't sure why Full text search stopped working and the best way to resolve this. Our server has maybe 100 databases.

We also found this article https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sql-server-2005-backups-in-a-hung-state-because-of-full-text-search-process that indicates full text search may not have resumed correctly, possibly indicating a corrupt catalog.

May I ask if anyone has any suggestions on how to resolve. We've turned off full text search for the time being and sql server is stable.

Comment: What does "*crashing our sql server*" mean?...do you have a specific error message you encountered and if so what was it?

Comment: Try rebuilding the catalog maybe `ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG [FT Name] REBUILD`